# How to substitute variable in data for making a POST request using urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to take the winusername and winpassword from the user as an argument and then use it in my POST request body. But unfortunately, it's not able to substitute the variables.

If I hardcode the values of winusername and winpassword in my "data" section of the POST request it works absolutely fine.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2
import base64
import json


# Collect all the inputs from the user
username = str(sys.argv[1])
password = str(sys.argv[2])
winusername = str(sys.argv[3])
winpassword = str(sys.argv[4])


data = '{\n    "extra_vars": {\n        "win_user": "% winusername",\n        "win_pass": "% winpassword"\n    }\n}'

request = urllib2.Request("https://awx-myorganization.net/api/v2/job_templates/212/launch/")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
CreateResponse = urllib2.urlopen(request,data)

data1 = json.load(CreateResponse)
```

Expected Results: winusername and winpassword should be taken from user as an argument and passed on to "data" section of POST request.

Note: I'm using Python version 2.6

Comment: I don't think you should be using 2.6 anymore

Comment: I understand that, but right now we can't upgrade the python version as this requires OS upgrade as well. Is there any way i can pass the variable ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working.

There was mistake in syntax.
Variable substitution would be - "win_user": "' + winusername + '"

Comment: If it was just a typo would you mind deleting the post as it might not be very helpful for others